# Google Map Geolocation and Showing a business type

Tags: google-maps-api-3, types, geolocation, google-places-api

First of all I would like to thank everyone could help me, and say that I am a begginer in developing.

I am trying to set up the code for a **Google Map with Geolocalization showing only markers on Car Rental type of places**. The idea is that when a visitor of my webpage get into the site the map geolocalize the visitor position and the map show only car rental places nearby.

I got the geolocalization google code:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
<script>
  // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
  // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
  // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
  // locate you.

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 6
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MYAPIKEY]&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

And it works fine, but now, I am reading about places and types and I don't succeed.

Any idea? Anybody can help me?

Best regards and thanks in advance.

Jordi V.
CarRentals.Deals

Answer (score 0):

The functions in the Google Places JavaScript library enable your application to search for places (defined in this API as establishments, geographic locations, or prominent points of interest) contained within a defined area, such as the bounds of a map, or around a fixed point.

The Google Places API offers an autocomplete feature which you can use to give your applications the type-ahead-search behavior of the Google Maps search field. When a user starts typing an address, autocomplete will fill in the rest. For more information, see the **[autocomplete documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete)**.

In my example, I used **Nearby Search** - lets you search for places within a specified area by keyword or type. It uses PlacesService's nearbySearch() method, which will return an array of PlaceResult objects. To learn more, you can check **[this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests)** link. Now let's take a look for the code breakdown.

```
 var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch({
                  location: location,
                  radius: 500,
                  type: ['car_rental']
 }, callback);
```

You can either use property 'bounds' or 'location', in our case, we are using 'location'. Note that if you are using 'location', you will also need to supply 'radius' property. The maximum allowed 'radius' is 50 000 meters. We also used 'type' property. It restricts the results to places matching the specified type. Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored). See the **[list of supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)**.

The callback function accepts two arguments. The result, and the status. You can make your own argument names. This (callback) is the place where we will add codes you wanted to execute if the 'status' argument is okay. The callback function:

```
function( results, stat ){
          if (stat === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
             for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              var place = results[i];
              createMarker(results[i], map);           
             }           
          }     
        });     

 });
```

If the result is okay, the returned values are in an array, so you need to iterate through each array and display them as Google Markers. To learn more about Google Markers, you can check **[this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)**. Here's the definition of createMarker function:

```
function createMarker(place, map) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
});
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

Complete code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    html,body,#map {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div> 
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=places">
</script>
<script>
function initMap() {
var map;
var infowindow;
// Try HTML5 geolocation.
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
var pos = {
lat: position.coords.latitude,
lng: position.coords.longitude
};
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center:location,
     zoom: 12
});
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch({
location: location,
radius: 500,
type: ['car_rental']
}, function( results, stat ){
if (stat === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
var place = results[i];
createMarker(results[i], map);           
}           
}     
});     
});
} else {
alert("Browser doesn't support Geolocation");
}
} 
function createMarker(place, map) {
var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.setContent(place.name);
  infowindow.open(map, this);
});
}    
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Working demo **[here](https://jsbin.com/bidigek/edit?html,output)**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi and Thank you very much. Works perfect!!! Hope it helps anyone else. Very best regards.

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you mind accepting it? Thanks :)